# I adopted my dog yesterday, I don't know what is his breed and how old do you think is he?

Tags: dogs

I want to buy a book on how to treat the puppy that I adopted yesterday, I don't know what is his breed and how old do you think is he?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately breed identification questions are off-topic here. Please read more information and reasons for that in the following [Meta Post](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/12501).

Comment: He's only young. He looks like he's 6-8 weeks old. Hard to say the breed - his ears look like shar pei, he also looks like possible staffordshire bull terrier, but it really could be a mixture of many breeds. How big is he and what does his tail look like? If you post a link to a bunch of pics and give a reference to his size it would help.

Comment: Awww hes so cute! You probably wont be able to determine his breed until he gets older however you can do a test to clarify.